# I am creating a gif in photoshop and have a lot of PS files to put in, but these files are in separate layers, can I change this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

To preface I know how to use the animation timeline. I have 200 PS images that I want imported, but they have multiple layers, so for each image I will need to group the layers, this seems tedious. Is there a way for them to come in automatically grouped or merged into one layer.

Comment: [So what you want is basically this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cKEfu.jpg), but with 200 documents instead of 5? Your title and your description is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it was confusing, but that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff.
Personally, I use two methods for solving this issue.

**The first one** - go to the layer window and select all layers by pressing SHIFT button. After that you press CTRL+G. This command groups all selected layers into a folder that you can import into another document.The big plus for this technique is that you can edit everything after that.The problem is that the file may become too big and your computer may become slower.

**The second technique** - Simply drag and drop all your files into one file. They will be placed like Smart objects and all of them will be on different layers. You can also edit each one of them by pressing right click on a layer and pressing "Edit Contents".

Hope you find this helpful. If you have questions, feel free to write :))

Cheers